# Why is there an additional "favicon.ico" HTTP request?

Tags: http, httprequest, favicon

Using the code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9744961/514773

I've noticed that any time I enter: http://localhost:8080 into my browser the output result is:

```
http://localhost:8080/

http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico
```

Subsequent requests print the same thing. This to me looks like I am getting two requests for price of one. Is this normal? (This is not my desired behavior.)

Comment: I think it's a browser behaviour. The `favicon.ico` is a standars used by some browser in their tabs. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1321878/422353

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Browsers automatically request the `favicon.ico` file by default when you issue a request for a web page. The `favicon.ico` file is the small icon that appears in the URL bar of your browser.

Answer (score 0):

How to suppress it though and where in case of jersey ?
Have seen the solution as :

```
<intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to *this* question. OP isn't asking to hide the request and it doesn't appear that OP is using jersey (in fact, OP uses C#).